# Zoom automático no marcador

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-location-api

Eu uso este código pra recuperar Lat e lang de um usuário no firebase,
Minha duvida é como dar um zoom automático (animado) no marcador...

```
mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Location childLocation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);
            LatLng childPos = new LatLng(childLocation.getLat(),childLocation.getLang());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions  =new MarkerOptions().position(childPos);
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            userMarkers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(),marker);


               }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use um objecto do tipo CameraUpdate juntamente com o método `animateCamera()`

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(childPos, zoom);
mMap.animateCamera(update);
```

Defina o valor de `zoom` de acordo com o zoom pretendido.